# Comments in SharePoint designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, 2016

I am working on SharePoint designer to customize page layout in SharePoint 2013

Is there any way to comment and uncomment code like visual studio buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SharePoint Designer is not considered a dedicated Code editor or IDE like Visual Studio, However, you can add a **comment tag** through

- Keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+/`.
- Or from Edit > Insert Tag > Insert comment.

  [image]

> **Note:** it's not working with the JS/CSS codes. it's only for HTML code.  Also, you will not able comment the highlighted code.

---

To add a comment on the highlighted HTML, JS, CSS codes, you can create a **Code Snippet** as mentioned at **[Comments in SharePoint Designer](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/11/17/comments-in-sharepoint-designer/)**

[image]

For more details, check **[Comments in SharePoint Designer](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/11/17/comments-in-sharepoint-designer/)**

Answer (score 2):

No handy buttons for this, but you can just type comment codes...

For HTML:

```
<!--
  code to comment out
-->
```

For JavaScript:

```
/*
  code to comment out
*/
```